# Does how recent your blockhash matter in regards to how quickly a transaction is confirmed?

Tags: transaction, blockhash

Does how recent a blockhash is matter? Do the validators do any sorting to make sure the majority of transactions get executed or avoid a larger percentage of transaction expiration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

The validator does not do any ordering based on how recent a blockhash a transaction has, only checks if it is valid.